# Rails 4: Paperclip - How to display Avatars for other users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Before I ask my question I need to mention right away that I am new to programming, web development and rails. I have tried to figure out the question myself, and I have also googled it, but I cant find a solution.

I am building a social network as a learning project, and using the Paperclip gem I am able to easily upload profile pictures, and I am able to display the avatar for the current logged in user.

When UserOne is logged in, he can upload a profile pic. It displays his own profile pic where it is supposed to. However when UserOne looks at UserTwo, UserOne's profile pic is the one displayed.

Using <%= image_tag(current_user.avatar.url(:thumb)) %> I am able to display my own Avatar Image.

What code would I use in my views to display other users? Edit to clarify: I need to show both the avatar for a second user, as well as a page where it lists all the users to the site.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: As Requested I am including my controller method. I hope I am pasting the right one!

```
def index
@users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
if params[:search]
  @users = User.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
else
  @users = User.all.order('created_at DESC')
end
```

end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

Comment: I see that my question was downrated. I am sure that I asked it wrong and apolagize to the community for that. I will try to figure it out myself and if I get the answer I will post it here so others that is new to this like I am might learn from it!

Answer (score 1):

In your case current_user has data of UserOne. Fetch the data of UserTwo and store it in another variable (say user_two ). Now by calling user_two.avatar.url(:thumb) you will get the image for the second user.

```
user_two = User.find 2
<%= image_tag(user_two.avatar.url(:thumb)) %>
```

the first line goes in your controller and the second in your view. ( User.find 2 will fetch the user details of the user with id=2 )

If you have trouble implementing it, share your controller method and view code.

EDIT

Controller

```
@users = User.all
```

This will fetch you the details of all the users and store it in @users.

View

```
<%= @users.each do |user| %>
<%= image_tag(user.avatar.url(:thumb)) %>
<%= end %>
```

The above code will display avatars of all the users.

Comment: Thank you Nihal. I think I understand what you mean, but I am at a loss on how to implement it. I posted the code as you requested. Thanks!